# Is it true that for every $n \times n$ matrix, $\text{det}(A^k) = (\text{det} A)^k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'd say yes, because

$\det(A^k) = \det(A) \det(A) \cdots \det(A) = (\det(A))^k$

But I might be missing something?

Comment: Yes, this property is true.

Comment: The same question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006102/if-a-is-some-invertible-n-times-n-matrix-then-show-detan-detan?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $\det AB = \det A \det B$ for all $n \times n$ matrices $A,B$.

$\det(A^k) = (\det(A))^k$ follows by induction on $k$.